# How to test model method django

Tags: django, testing, django-models

I write test to my app and I don't know how to test this model method:

```
def has_recipe(self):
    if self.type in [101, 102, 103, 104, 201, 301, 302, 303, 304]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

When I write test like this:

```
def test_has_recipe(self):
    book = Book(type in [101, 102, 103, 104, 201, 301, 302, 303, 304])
    self.assertTrue(book, [101, 102, 103, 104, 201, 301, 302, 303, 304])
```

The test passes, but without coverage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a book in your test, then call its `has_recipe` method.

You could try something like:

```
def test_has_recipe(self):
    book = Book(type=101)
    self.assertTrue(book.has_recipe())
```